# How to place all drilldown groups on same row - SSRS reporting

Tags: reporting-services

How would I place all drilldown groups onto the same row on an SSRS report?

I've got it working on separate rows as you can see from the attached JPG.

Please advise the SSRS programming method.

Thank you very much.

[image: image jpg]

Comment: Without actually looking at the layout.. can take a guess that you have multiple column groups.. rather than separate groups.. what if you make them child group of the first group?

Comment: How will "Yes" and "No" (*Top Application Segment*) fit into only one row?

Comment: @Harry No, I actually do not have multiple column groups.  I have multiple row groups, which are hierarchical in nature: System Owner being on the top of the hierarchy, the one lower level down: Top Application, then even lower level down from Top application, Segment, etc, etc.

Comment: @WolfgangKais the two rows No and Yes are actually showing because "No" has been collapsed.  If "No" was not collapsed, "Yes" will be showing much farther down the report.

Comment: @Harry any further ideas Harry?

Comment: What is the System Owner of these 2 "Yes" and "No"? Since "Adam" is collapsed, all of these subgroups should be hidden, shouldn't they? What is expaded when you click on the "+" next to "Adam"? Please show the design of the report.

Comment: @WolfgangKais "-" means collapsed Wolfgang, not "+".  Wolfgang, the design of the report is such that the first four columns are drilldowns.  From Product Name inclusive onwards to the right, they are not drilldowns, but are simply tabular list data.  Does this help?

Comment: No. "-" means "click me to collapse" (so currently *expanded* details are shown), and "+" means "click me to expand" (so currently *collapsed* details are shown).

Answer (score 1):

To toggle the visibility a group (the groups defined by a dataset field), this should be done using a control belonging to its parent group.

For example: To toggle the visibility of the *Top Appliction* groups ("Yes" and "No" and everything underneath), select the *System Owner* textbox as the toggle control in the visibility settings of the *Top Appliction* group poperties.